# SetTitle of Data Picker instead of getting Today Date in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had a datepicker in which I am getting default system date during its Initialization.But I don't want default date.I need to get a Title(Select Date) similar to PikcerTitle in Xamarin.Forms. Anyone please help me to bring a solution for my problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a label and datepicker instead of just datepicker and hide datepicker. Add a tap gesture to the label, on the tap focus the datepicker and bind the text of the label to the datepicker's date.

On page load add your desired text in the label.

Comment: Thank You Ashish.But during Label GestureRecognizerevent we can just hide the label right.But cannot get the datepicker on screen.I mean user cannot select date with the sigle click on label.Sorry for my English.

Comment: on Tap gesture use DatePicker.Focus() , it will show the datepicker